# Unable to load dll in Console or Web API project

Tags: exception, dll, load

I'm experiencing a rather strange problem.

I'm trying to interface with a Wacom signature pad, and would like to build a web service wrapper for the pad's API so that I can capture a signature on a website.

The signature pad requires two dll's to work: STUTablet.dll and STUTabletCore.dll.

I have a class library that references STUTablet.dll. Both dll files are in the class library's bin directory.

If I reference my class library from a Windows Forms application, I am able to call methods that call STUTablet.dll. However, if I reference my class library from a console application or an MVC application, an exception is thrown.

The exception is as follows: Unable to load DLL 'STUTabletCore.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

I have tried adding the same references that a default Windows Forms application has to my Console application, but to no avail.

Does anybody have any idea as to why STUTablet.dll is unable to load STUTabletCore.dll? There has to be some kind of dependency that I'm not fulfilling.

Thanks,

Francis :)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues but eventually got help from Wacom UK support team and managed to get 
a web based application to work on IE only with ActiveX.

Try
http://gsdt.wacom.eu/download/Signature-SDK.xml

Choose either 32 or 64 bit Signature SDK installer, plenty of SDK examples

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up writing a minimizeable Windows Forms application, as me and my colleagues were unable to get it to work in a service context.